# How to retrieve values from 2 arrays and dispaly in a specific format

Tags: angular, typescript

this my code to retrieve values from data of arrays, i need to use in specific format,my code return values in [][] foramt

```
{
  data1= ["asd","acv","qwe"];
  data2 = [12,223,23];
  data1.forEach(s => {
        data2.forEach(v=>{
          this.multi=[
            {
              "name":s,
              "value":v,
            }
          ];
        })

      });
 }
```

what i need is ,

```
{
  "name":"asd",
   "value":12
},
{
  "name:"acv",
  "value":223
},
{
  "name":"qwe"
   "value":23
}
```

how to get this?
any one help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `foreach` with the `index`

```js
 
 let data1= ["asd","acv","qwe"];
 let data2 = [12,223,23];  
   let arr = [] 
   
data1.forEach((item, index) => {
   arr.push({
    'name': item,
    'value': data2[index]
   })
  })
  
  console.log(arr)
```

Comment: sure. make sure to check as answer if this helped

Comment: how to make both arrays length as same with values..What i mean is data1 has only one element and data2 have 10 ...i need to make data1 array one value to 10

Comment: `{  "name":"acv",value:12 },{"name":"acv,value:20}{"name":"acv,value:21}                                         }`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need both arrays to have the same lenght. If both have the same length you easily could do it with a simple for loop:

```
var merged = [];
for ( let c=0; c<data1.length;c++) {
   merged.push({name:data1[c], value:data2[c]});
}
```